# Asset Allocation Tools that understand Mutual Funds

Tags: online-tools, asset-allocation

I am looking for a tool that will help me understand my current asset allocation given that I invest only in mutual funds.  What I want is something where I can enter my current fund share balances and it will examine each fund's asset classes to give me an overall picture.

I currently have a number of investment and retirement accounts with two different brokerages, and neither of them offers a tool that will integrate all the data. I have also searched on the web but found nothing that can do this relatively simple (if tedious) task.  I could do this with Excel, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if it already exists.

I'm not looking for advice, just something that can tell me where I am currently and allow me to play with what-if scenarios.

EDIT:

I ran across [Portfolio Monkey](https://portfoliomonkey.com/), which looks promising.  If it does what I need I'll post my impressions as an answer.

Comment: If you get the version of Money or Quicken or whatever that handles investments, it should be able to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Morningstar has facilities that allow one to enter data from any number of portfolios of mutual funds, and it will not only allow you to compare asset allocations but will give you *estimates* of overlap in investments in different mutual funds (e.g. tell you how much of your money is invested in a particular stock even when the holdings are spread over several different
mutual funds. Only estimates can be provided because the *exact* holdings of 
each mutual fund on any particular day are not known outside the mutual
fund, though educated guesses can be made by those who keep an eye out for
such information. 
Some of Morningstar's facilities are accessible only to those who pay a fee 
while others are accessible to anyone who visits their site.  Some large 
mutual fund houses offer free Morningstar memberships to clients who have invested substantial assets with them; perhaps your brokerage house(s) 
also might offer such a benefit to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very interested on this topic as well and I like the idea of [sigfig.com](https://www.sigfig.com/). Unfortunately, it seems they are single-currency (USD) and single-country (USA), which is very unfortunate for me, as a resident of EU.

Comment: I tried out sigfig.com as I'm based in the US. The total account value numerically was accurate, but the historical values were wrong. The total value of the account was 36. The plots showed the variation between 39 and 45, completely different from the actual value. After about three days on the site, my total account value was indicated to have dropped by 9.5%.  I checked each individual investment, and nothing seemed to have changed by anything near that amount. I spent several days waiting for their customer service people trying to resolve both issues, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

[Personal Capital](https://www.personalcapital.com/) is a go-to tool for looking at a consolidated view across multiple accounts with different brokerages. However, it doesn't really offer any what-if scenario analysis built-in.

For what-if analysis or testing alternative portfolio constructions, you should consider [Hellomoney.co](https://hellomoney.co/).